# Angular 5 ng-repeat implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular5

I'm trying to implement a basic example of ng-repeat. I'm using ionic 3 and Angular 5. I don't know what the problem is? Help me with the code.

**manage.html**

```
<ul *ngFor="let room of roomDetail; let i = index">
     <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in room">
      {{key}} : {{value}}
      </li>
  </ul>
```

**manage.ts**

```
import {
    Component
}
from '@angular/core';
import {
    IonicPage, NavController, NavParams
}
from 'ionic-angular';@
IonicPage()@ Component({
    selector: 'page-manage',
    templateUrl: 'manage.html',
})
export class ManagePage {
    public room = {};
    public roomDetail = [{
        "roomName": "Room-1",
        "floorNumber": "2nd Floor",
        "buildingName": "Golden Millenium"
}];
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

}
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any error? What is the consequence of  the problem you're having?

Comment: nothing is displaying. No error.

Comment: You should use `*ngFor` instead of `ng-repeat` for angular 2+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use pipe to iterate over object keys.

```
<ul *ngFor="let room of roomDetail; let i = index">
     <li *ngFor="let key of room | keys">
      {{key}} : {{room[key]}}
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Pipe

```
@Pipe({ name: 'keys',  pure: false })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value)//.map(key => value[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So is it another export class keysPipe I need to include? Because it is showing me "Pipe 'keys' could not be found".

Answer (score 5):

`ng-repeat` does not exist anymore in Angular 2+. You have a couple of options.
If a `roomDetail` always has the same format, you can do the following:

```
<ul *ngFor="let room of roomDetail; let i = index">
     <li>
        RoomName : {{room.roomName}}
     </li>
     <li>
        FloorNumber : {{room.floorNumber}}
     </li>
     <li>
        BuildingName : {{room.buildingName}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

A bit more involved would be a transformation in your ManagePage:

```
getIterableRoomDetails = (room, index) => Object.keys(room).map(key => ({key: key, data: this.roomDetail[index][key]}))
```

With your template like:

```
<ul *ngFor="let room of roomDetail; let i = index">
     <li *ngFor="let details of getIterableRoomDetails(room, index)">
        {{details.key}} : {{details.data}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm getting Typescript error: ';' expected here in ===> data: this.roomDetail[index][key]

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for coding just here. I've updated my answer. The problem was that `key => {key: ...` is wrong syntax. It should be (and I updated my answer) `key => ({key: ...`. Notice the `=> (`. It leads to being interpreted as `return {key: ...}`

Answer (score 1):

Update your code with :

```
<ul *ngFor="let room of roomDetail; let i = index">
 <li>
  {{room.roomName}} : {{room.floorNumber}}
  </li>
```

It might display name and foolrnumber.

Comment: since my object is dynamic, every time I can't give it's key.